# Separate md-tab-header and tab body with Angular 4 Material

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to separate the md-tab-header and the actual content body regarding Angular Material's tabs component. The reason behind this is because I want the header in a different container than the body itself, with separate styling. Here's my code so far:

```
<div id="tabs-header-container">
        <md-tab-group md-stretch-tabs="always" (selectChange)="onLinkClick($event)">
            <md-tab class="uk-width-1-2">
                <ng-template md-tab-label>
                    <i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </ng-template>
                <p>Chat body, this should have its own container</p>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab class="uk-width-1-2">
                <ng-template md-tab-label>
                    <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </ng-template>
                <p>Referral body, this should have its own container</p>
            </md-tab>
          </md-tab-group>
    </div>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Could you setup a plunker/stackblitz, please?

Comment: that is not possible by design.

Comment: @Faisal How would you suggest achieving a separate tab header and body? It doesn't have to be Material, as long as it works with Angular. Preferably the same design as Material though. I tried looking for other CSS frameworks and their implementation of tabs but nothing fitted my needs.

Comment: why dont you just select `md-tab-group` via `.mat-tab-group` in css

Comment: If you you navigate (using router) between tabs you can do that using `mat-tab-nav-bar`